# SessionNotCreated Could not start - After upgrade from selenium 4.16 to 4.17

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have made upgrade from selenium 4.13 to 4.17. With version 4.16 the tests are OK. On version 4.17 I have this exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 

Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: '.......', ip: '.........'
Build info: version: '4.18.0', revision: 'b6bf9de7cc*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}]}]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpHeader
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpHeader
```

I have checked dependencies and set newest versions. Chrome version is 122.0.6261.58, Chrome driver version is 122.0.6261.57.